# Choosing data points for multiple regression

Tags: multiple-regression, simulation, prediction-interval

I am building a regression model from simulation data. Specifically, I can choose which data points to sample and want to minimize my average prediction interval in the prediction space $[L,U]$.

In the one-dimensional case, my I am computing my prediction interval as: $$PI(y)=MSE*\left[ 1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{(x_{new}-\bar x)^2}{\sum_{\forall i} (x_i-\bar x)^2}  \right]$$

It seems to me that, to obtain a minimal average prediction interval, I should 'observe' points as wide from the center as possible to maximize the term $\sum_{\forall i} (x_i-\bar x)^2$.

Does a similar logic apply to the multivariate regression case? Should I maximize the average distance between all data points, or should I simply sample data points at the edges of the prediction space? How can I mathematically justify this procedure?
[image: Data point sampling in 3D]

Ultimately, I am looking to systematically decrease prediction intervals by intelligent data selection, as is shown in this graph (reduction by ~14%).
[image]